# sql get count of month

Tags: sql, t-sql, charts, sql-server-express

In SQLExpress, I have a table that contains a datetime-column. It is formatted like this:

```
19.03.2012 00:00:00
```

Now, there are a lot of dates in there and I want to build a WPFChart, that shows me, how much dates are in march, in april and so on. 
How can I manage this in sql that I get the count of one month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
select month(dateColumn), count(*)
from table
group by month(dateColumn)
```

Comment: You can't `select dateColumn, count(*)`, you need to `select month(dateColumn), count(*)`.  Also, this answer should advise the OP that Jan2011 and Jan2012 will get merged into one record.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the month of a date with [Month()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187813.aspx) funciton.
than with a simple group by, you get the count for every month

Comment: You are right, I based the answer on the assumption that when I do this kind of reports I usually get the months of a specific year.

Answer (score 1):

To get *only* one month...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  SUM(valueColumn)
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      dateColumn >= '20120101'
  AND dateColumn <  '20120201'
```

To get multiple months, but grouped by month (and accounting for year).

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dateColumn), 0),
  COUNT(*),
  SUM(valueColumn)
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      dateColumn >= '20110301'
  AND dateColumn <  '20120301'
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dateColumn), 0)
```